# How to view an unlisted Photosynth, without a Windows Live account?

Tags: windows-live

I created [this unlisted (but now stated in public) photosynth](http://photosynth.net/edit.aspx?cid=aa354391-40ec-44f9-9449-3e0612afc124&wa=wsignin1.0) People are required to log into a Windows Live account to see it.  Is there a public link to it that I can share?

Answer (score 1):

From the Photosynth website http://photosynth.net/ if you choose [My Photosynths] and click on one, it will be shown along with "sharing" links below it.  Use the EMBED link to access the direct URL. The user will not have to be logged into a Windows Live account.